# PHP creating a 404 for a hidden directory

Tags: php, http-status-code-404

I am currently developing a web application and am trying to keep some basic directory names (i.e libs) hidden to as prevent further poking from anyone looking to find vulnerabilities in the application.

I figure the best way to do this would be to do this;

```
<?php
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
?>

<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at 178.128.93.102 Port 80</address>

<?php
    die();
?>
```

in an index.php file in the directory.

This does show the correct information to the page, and I assume the same to any tools in which would check for valid directories given the 404 header. However, if one were to look manually, the URL corrects from http://localhost/libs to http://localhost/libs/. This indicates that the directory does actually exist, hence the added '/'. A true 404 does not add the '/', as the server would have no idea whether or not text indicated a file or directory.

Is there any way I am able to show a 404 without correcting this '/'? This may be completely over the top, but better safe than sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Real question is : what do you really need ? Pretend your /libs directory does not exists ? Or prevent people seeing what's inside of it ?

If your true concern is to prevent people seeing your libs, your should not bother yourself with the trailing slash problem.
Best solution for me is to use your server configuration, if Apache this will do the trick :

```
<Directory /path/to/your/libs>
  Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

BUT

**Hidding your libs will never mean you do not have to update them for security patches.**

Most important point for me : **if you do not trust any of these libraries** and think they may have so much vulnerabilies you have to hide them : **DROP IT** and use another one !